# Unit test on redux that involves a firebase call

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux

I have a actionCreator method that I would like to do unit test on. It will make a firebase call and on success or fail it will dispatch 2 methods relatively.

It looks sth like this:

```
export function removeItem(itemId) { 
   return dispatch => {
       return firebase.database().ref('items').child(itemId).remove()
           .then(
                 success => dispatch(updateList()),
                 error => dispatch(failRemovingItem(error))
           );
       };
}
```

I am following the example from redux. http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html

But I am not able to mock the firebase call via nock.

Does anyone have experience with unit-testing something similar?

Answer (score 0):

One of the scenarios is to extract line:

```
firebase.database().ref('items').child(itemId).remove()
```

to the helper, for example, FireBasehelper.removeEntity(id) and then you can easily mock this helper inside action creator by following common practices. Your code then would look like this:

```
export function removeItem(itemId) { 
   return dispatch => {
       return Databasehelper.removeEntity(itemId)
           .then(
                 success => dispatch(updateList()),
                 error => dispatch(failRemovingItem(error))
           );
       };
}
```

In the helper, you only returning what we've just extracted so

```
 function removeEntity(itemId) { 
     return firebase.database().ref('items').child(itemId).remove()
 }
```